# Compilation error when using together a Factory and a method doing type capture

Tags: java, generics

I have run into a problem when using generics together with a factory and a method doing a capture of types.

I've isolated my problem in a dummy scenario using two entities, a factory and a test:

Interface for Parents. There is a bidirectional relationship between parents and children so both P and C types need to be part of the generic specification.

```
public class Parent<P extends Parent<P, C>, C extends Child<P, C>> {

    private List<C> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChild(C child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public List<C> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
}
```

The same applies to children.

```
public class Child<P extends Parent<P, C>, C extends Child<P, C>> {

    private P parent;

    public P getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(P parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

A pretty simple factory for parents.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ParentFactory {
    Parent<?, ?> create();
}
```

And the test showcasing the compilation problem:

```
public class GenericsTest {

    @Test
    public void testMakeTwin() {

        ParentFactory parentFactory = () -> new FooParent();

        // No problem here, makeTwin can infere the type of the parameter
        this.makeTwin(new FooParent());

        // No problem here either
        this.makeTwinIgnoringGenerics(parentFactory.create());

        // Does not compile! Why?
        this.makeTwin(parentFactory.create());
    }

    /**
     * This is just a dummy example of an operation that needs to capture both C and P
     */
    private <P extends Parent<P, C>, C extends Child<P, C>> void makeTwin(P parent) {

        List<C> children = parent.getChildren();
        if (children != null && !children.isEmpty()) {
            parent.addChild(children.iterator().next());
        }
    }

    private void makeTwinIgnoringGenerics(Parent parent) {

        // A lot of "this is a raw type" warnings in this method

        List children = parent.getChildren();
        if (children != null && !children.isEmpty()) {
            // This is safe because the child comes from the same parent, but that's something the compiler can't know
            parent.addChild((Child) children.iterator().next());
        }
    }

    private static class FooParent extends Parent<FooParent, FooChild> {
    }

    private static class FooChild extends Child<FooParent, FooChild> {
    }
}
```

Why is the test not able to cast the parent created by the factory to the parameter expected by the method `makeTwin`?

Addendum:

The concrete question is: Why is the compiler not capable of capturing (and casting) the P and C concrete types returned by the factory?

Some extra info about the real scenario explaining why the test is the way it is. The real context is an application implementing a DDD architecture, the code in this test here would be in a service in the application layer and the factory here belongs to the domain layer. That is why the factory can not be parameterized, the factory decides what are the concrete C and P types to be created, and the test (that is the application service) does not care about them, it only needs to know that P and C are valid, that is they are related to each other.

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, **a specific** problem or **error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`Parent<?, ?>` is not same as `Parent<FooParent, FooChild>`.

Lets take a different implementation of `Parent`:

```
 private static class OtherFooFooParent extends Parent<FooParent, FooChild> {}
```

We can still create factory that returns the above `Parent`:

```
 ParentFactory parentFactory = () -> new OtherFooFooParent();
```

But `OtherFooFooParent` is not compatible with `P extends Parent<P, C>, C extends Child<P, C>` because `FooChild` is still bound to `FooParent`, and it is not valid to be passed to `makeTwin` method.

That's why compiler is complaining that it cannot make sure that `ParentFactory` will create `Parent` that is compatible with `makeTwin` method parameter.

The solution is to define `ParentFactory` to be bound to the same generics as `makeTwin` method is.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ParentFactory <P extends Parent<P, C>, C extends Child<P, C>> {
    P create();
}
```

And change this:

```
ParentFactory<FooParent, FooChild> parentFactory = () -> new FooParent();
```

Comment: The ParentFactory object reference in the test can not know the exact type of the Parent to be created. An Abstract factory hides the concrete type of the object created. Also, if ParentFactory interface was parameterized then the client should provide the concrete type to be created, but that is not what is wanted. I will explain this in more detail in an addendum to the question.

Comment: You dont need to provide concrete type to `ParentFactory`. The parameterization of `ParentFactory` is only need to make sure that it returns Parent that conform to `P extends Parent<P, C>, C extends Child<P, C>` type. Without doing so compiler wont be able to guarantee that client will get Parent that  is "it only needs to know that P and C are valid, that is they are related to each other".